# Other than strings what can i pass to message queue?

Tags: c#, msmq, message-queue

At very high level i would like to know apart from strings what (information) can i pass to Message Queues in C#.NET.

Simply to say that what are all things that can i can pass/send to a message queue by preparing a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others said, you can put anything into a message queue that can be serialized. [Here is an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) that can help get you up to speed on the basics of serialization.

Answer (score 2):

Anything you can serialize to a string depending on the message queue on the back end.  MSMQ has a 4MB message size limit, so objects that serialize to over 4Mb won't go (I hope no one has any of those...).  I believe this is correct through MSMQ 5.0.  More info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/08/22/why-is-there-a-4mb-limit-on-msmq-messages.aspx) on the size limit.

Answer (score 1):

Any object that can be serialised.